# What is the JavaScript equivalent for the vbscript Chr() function?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I need to convert following lines to JavaScript:

```
cOrderNumList = frmSearch.OrderNumList.Value
cOrderNumList = Replace(cOrderNumList, Chr(10), "")
aOrderNumList = Split(cOrderNumList,",")
```

What is the JavaScript equivalent of `Chr(10)`

Comment: This is a super-useful question. Why in the world was it closed?

Comment: Nominating for reopening as it's a useful question (of eminently googleable), and it is *completely* clear what the question is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
cOrderNumList = frmSearch.OrderNumList.Value;
cOrderNumList = cOrderNumList.replace(String.fromCharCode(10), "");
aOrderNumList = cOrderNumList.split(",");
```

Are my changes correct?

Comment: According to the question we need to split by ",". so last line should be `aOrderNumList = cOrderNumList.split(",");`

Comment: @←Madura Harshana. "," is the defaul seprator.

Answer (score 12):

You need [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode):

```
cOrderNumList = Replace(cOrderNumList, String.fromCharCode(10), "")
```

Answer (score 4):

To convert a char code to a string you can do this:

```
var outputString = yourString.replace(cOrderNumList, String.fromCharCode(10))
```

As you will notice, this converts the char code to a one-letter string. You can't truly convert to a pure char because the char type doesn't exist in JavaScript.

Comment: I think the Replace should be written in small caps.

Comment: yp.. thanx. `var outputString = yourString.replace(cOrderNumList, String.fromCharCode(10))` isnt that required to replace this with empty string `""`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) but if your character is hardcoded, the best is to simply use `"\n"`.

And as replace would only replace the first one, I suggest this simple regular expression :

```
cOrderNumList = cOrderNumList.replace(/\n/g, "")
```